# How to get first key's value from a flat jsonb field in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have localized `jsonb` column with data like `{"en": "Atmosphere", "ja": "雰囲"}` . I can extract it using `field->'en'`. I want to get a fallback, the first/any value in case the given locale (say 'es') is missing. Is this possible?

I'm using Postgres 13

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: I am using Postgres 13.

Comment: how would you define "fallback"? Would you have a separate fallback element in your json object or is some language guaranteed to exist (like 'en') ?

Comment: For example, if the field is `{"cn": "囲囲"}` and `field->en` is null, I need to get 囲囲. row is guaranteed to have atleast one key.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a function for that:

```
create or replace function get_value_with_fallback(p_data jsonb, p_key text)
  returns text
as
$$
  select p_data ->> p_key
  where p_data ? 'en'
  union all
  select value
  from jsonb_each_text(p_data) as d(key, value)
  where not p_data ? p_key
  limit 1;
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
select get_value_with_fallback(t.data, 'en')
from the_table t
```

As this is a simple SQL function that can be defined as immutable, this is essentially the same as embedding that UNION query directly into your SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there is a better solution using path syntax. I can suggest using ORDER BY for that. Getting "en" translation or falling back to any other value:

```
SELECT
  value
FROM 
  jsonb_each('{"cn": "囲囲", "lt":"test"}'::jsonb)
ORDER BY
  key = 'en' DESC --position matching translation first
LIMIT 1
```

You take first - either the one that you are searching for, or any value.